Rafters pulling apart from center support
Some of the rafters are coming apart in my attic. What is the best way for me to resolve this issue?
Please note that a new roof was just put on over the problem. The roofer assured me that he would better secure them but he didn't. I take responsibility because it wasn't detailed in the contract. But I'm at a loss about what to do now. Is this something I can hire a handman for? What, specifically, needs to happen for it to pass inspection, when I sell in 3 years?



I would get an architect and/or an experienced framer to look at this, not a handyman.  It looks like some repairs have already been attempted.   We can't tell from the photos what problem they were supposed to solve or whether they are effective.

Why can't you call the roofer back? You have attic access, anything they would have done while the roof was open can be done down here as well. At least he should cut you a decent rate since you spoke of it before.

What do you mean by: "Please note that a new roof was just put on over the problem."  Was that just a new set of tiles/shingles/slates, or are you talking about anything more structural?

A good portion of the sheathing and all of the shingles were replaced.

Firstly, know that this probably isn't a serious problem. Zillions of roofs from the hand-framing days have sagged and settled and separated in spots. They don't collapse. I can see why you'd want to fix it, though I'd only bother with the worst of these. The one in the first photo doesn't concern me.
Chances are the roofer locked the hip rafters in position when he installed the sheathing. You won't be able to move them without tearing things up and possibly jeopardizing your roofing.
So the thing to do is this:

Study hip roof framing a bit to understand the angles at play. (A valley like this is simply the converse counterpart of a hip ridge; its angles are identical.) You have a hip/valley plumb cut and you have a 45° miter. Seeing how that comes together is key to getting the cuts right for your repair.

Install some scabs (rafter extensions) to span the gaps. Use ~24-30" lengths of matching lumber (2x6), fit well to the jack rafter (which forms the valley), and fastened well with 12d nails or 2½" screws to the existing rafter and 16d or 3" screws to the jack rafter. Fit them on whichever side has the most clearance.



This 51 year in the business carpenter understood it very well, he is correct about the symptoms, although I would correct it with metal framing angles like adjustable L50s or the like. On top of that, thats still over kill, but it does something to appease a future inspector. In essence the roof is fine, looks rough, but will stand over time.

I'm not familiar with that hardware in the context of open spans. Most of it expects the lumber to be fit well, in my experience, keeping loads in shear.

Thank you everyone. Your comments helped me to narrow down the best course of action which, I believe, is to have a few experienced framing carpenters put their eyes on it and weigh in and then hire one to do the work.

@isherwood, I agree, it should fit well, but in this context, to make what is there fit well, is not possible/practical. The roof sheathing is part of that problem. Adding metal angles will not be easy in the tight space, with utilities running through the same space. It may be easier than adding the wood blocks/scabs/short sisters, which would work too, it would be the matter of getting them in place and those fitting well too.

Couldn't you add a hangar plate?  I normally see these for square connections, so the angles here would complicate things.  I was just thinking you could either build a customized piece or they might have hangars for standard angles that meet this case.

Hangers don't typically allow for substantial gaps, as I mentioned earlier.
